# HighStock Data Format Not working

Tags: angularjs, rest, highcharts

I'm having a lot of trouble getting my HighStock chart to render the data.  The chart shows up fine, but there are no data points and no time frame.  I'm using AngularJS to make a call to my RestAPI method.  This method returns an array of date and close values.

```
**c#**
public object[] Get(string symbol)
    {
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-365);
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;

        List<HistoryQuote> hq_list = StockEngine.GetHistory(symbol, startDate, endDate);

        List<object> output = new List<object>();
        foreach (var h in hq_list)
        {
            // in the format [1223337600000,12.74]
            output.Add(new object[] { JsonFriendlyDate(h.Date), h.Close });
        }

        return output.ToArray();

    }

    public long JsonFriendlyDate(DateTime value)
    {
        return (value.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - ((new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).Ticks)) / 10000;
    }
```

Below is the JavaScript I use to create the chart and bind the data:

```
var params = { symbol: stock };
    services.HistorySvc.query(params,
        function success(data) {
            $scope.StockListLoading = false;
            $('.modal').modal('hide');

            $scope.ShowHistory = true;
            $('#history_container').highcharts('StockChart', {

                rangeSelector: {
                    selected: 1
                },

                title: {
                    text: stock + ' Stock Price'
                },

                series: [{
                    name: stock + ' Stock Price',
                    data: data,
                    type: 'area',
                    threshold: null,
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    },
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: {
                            x1: 0,
                            y1: 0,
                            x2: 0,
                            y2: 1
                        },
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    }
                }]
            });


        }, function error(err) {
            alert("Hmm. History service failed.  Weird!");
            $scope.StockListLoading = true;
        });
```

HistorySvc is defined as:

```
HistorySvc: $resource('/API/History/:id', { 'id': '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } })
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I receive valid data back from the api call, but it appears to not be in the format the chart wants.

When I run the highstock example in jsfiddle, their API call is returning [[1000202, 102.4],[12388388,10.9]].  Mine returns the exact same format, but the chart does not render the points. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: HighChart support arrays as well as JSON objects. Can you provide the  JSON data the server returns to the browser? BTW. You shouldn't mix angular and plain old jQuery. At least put everything in a `directive` or use the ng module: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

Comment: The data being return is like so:    [[1444104000000,21.129999],[1444017600000,20.940001],[1443758400000,20.299999],[1443672000000,19.57],[1443585600000,18.969999],[1443499200000,18.84],[1443412800000,18.690001],[1443153600000,18.91],[1443067200000,20.90],[1442980800000,21.389999],[1442894400000,21.85],[1442808000000,22.889999],[1442548800000,23.18],[1442462400000,23.90],[1442376000000,23.35],[1442289600000,23.469999],[1442203200000,22.90],[1441944000000,23.200001],[1441857600000,23.190001]]

Comment: The data is sorted descending instead of ascending. Except of that it is ok and I can render it in a plain StockChart. See http://jsfiddle.net/jwudy544/1/. The problem must be in your implementation. Please provide a Plunker for further support.

Comment: @AnthonySG share a jsfiddle in your question. It always makes answering the question 10x easier.